# How to deal with smart_ptr when class method returns reference

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers

In my project i would like to use smart_ptrs instead of raw pointers.
Now if a class method returns a pointer to itself, how can i deal with this using smart_pointers correctly?

```
class bar{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<bar> foo(){std::shared_ptr<bar>(this);}
};

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<bar>();
    auto b = a->foo();
    std::cout << a.use_count() << std::endl; //outputs 1 
}
```

Comment: [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) is the answer, but why do you want everything to be managed with a `std::shared_ptr`? Mandating dynamic allocation for everything will likely murder your performance.

Comment: Use a member variable of the class which is a smart_ptr to itself?

Comment: can i use smart_ptrs for objects allocated on the stack?

Comment: @Exagon Not without a custom no-op deleter. But why would you want to?

Comment: @Exagon: No, and why would you? They are automatically deleted anyway

Comment: No. And why do you ever want to do that? The stack is already managed.

Comment: because i would like to know how many references are active to the objects

Comment: but thats another question. i think std::enable_shared_from_this is what i was searching for

Comment: I hope you are aware, that *"managing every object by a smart pointer"* isn't the same as *"not using raw pointers at all"*. The former is a questionable goal. the latter is downright stupid.

Comment: Also,if all you want is to get a reference count, then using shared_ptr everywhere is definitely not the way to do it.

Comment: I will write 2 more questions, because I see the problem but its not realy related to this specific question anymore.

Comment: You forgot `return`, but `return std::shared_ptr<bar>(this);` is wrong anyway.